# How do I find dimension and basis of $\ker A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find dimension and basis of $\ker A$ if $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\   0&3  &0  &0  & 1 &0 \\   0&1  &0  &0  &0  &3  \end{pmatrix} $?

To find the kernel of a matrix $A$ is the same as to solve the system $Ax = 0$. Done that.

$x=\begin{pmatrix}
-18x+2y\\ 
-3x\\ 
z\\ 
y\\ 
9x\\ 
x\end{pmatrix}$

But what is dimension and basis of that?

Comment: Hint: $\dim \ker A+\dim\operatorname{Im} A=n$ for a $m\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Row reduce your matrix to find the linearly independent columns (for image space or the "rank" of the matrix). By the rank-nullity theorem:
$$\operatorname{null}(A) + \operatorname{img}(A) = n.$$
And you have your answer.